# How to Iterate Data in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to iterate this data on vue inside the method function

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Jack Daniels",
      "mobile": "21223",
      "start": "2021-02-25T09:16:21.000000Z",
      "end": "2021-02-25T09:16:21.000000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

here is my code

```js
async getEvents() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/customers')

        Object.entries(response).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            console.log(`${key}:${value}`)
        })

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

and here is the output on

```
data:[object Object],[object Object]
```

any idea what went wrong and if there is better approach for iterating the data in vue.js

Comment: data contains an array containing one object. You have to access the array index 0 and then you get the object

Comment: also what do you mean by method function?

Comment: You might also want to log out the actual entries rather than their string representations, `console.log('key',key); console.log('value',value);`

Comment: just console.log(response) and you will see what to do

Comment: @ccarstens not sure on the terms but I think its called method handler forgive my ignorance

Comment: @kevmc I tried your code but its only giving me one data suppose I have more than one data how can I Iterate those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's not Vue question(axios/js tags). 
You don't need Object.entries here (if you need to iterate data array).
Just use map for array and that's all.

```
const iteratedData = response.data.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(`Index ${index}`);
    console.log(item);
    // Do what you need with data, your iteration
    return item;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay and for your correction, I tried the code but am getting this error TypeError: response.data.map is not a function

Comment: @EdsonTeliaken Can you just log it to console? To see actual structure

Comment: @ Asimple  am getting this one `TypeError: response.data.map is not a function
    at _callee$ (app.js:2526)
    at tryCatch (app.js:38812)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (app.js:39042)
    at Generator.next (app.js:38867)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (app.js:2283)
    at _next (app.js:2285)`

Comment: @EdsonTeliaken I've understood problem with it. Just `console.log(response)` to see actual object and find out through which property you should iterate. Because there can be response data, and `data of data`, so maybe you should access it like: `response.data.data.map`

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine. Here key is data and value is array of object. so to access value, here is a sample code

```
let response = {
 "data":[{
 "id":1,
 "name":"Jack Daniels",
 "mobile":"21223",
 "start":"2021-02-25T09:16:21.000000Z",
 "end":"2021-02-25T09:16:21.000000Z"
 }]
};
Object.entries(response).forEach(([key,value])=>{
          console.log(`${key}:${value[0].id}`)
})
```

Here value is an array so iterate value to get properties. It is just a sample to show logic.

Comment: Hey man thanks for your replay suppose I have more than one data do iterate how can I achieve this? thanks

Comment: You can use foreach to iterate over array of object